# Как посчитать все возможные пути в графе

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы, структуры-данных

Есть граф с N ребер и V вершин.
Есть стартовая S и конечная F вершины.
Как посчитать максимальное количество путей длины Long, по которым его можно обойти?

Comment: Вопрос не до конца ясен, есть стартовая вершина и конечная для обхода?

Comment: да верно. я поправил вопрос. через матрицы смежности не вариант очень не эффективно получается.

Comment: Решение на c++, java, python:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-two-vertices/. По поводу длины Long. В ходе поиска пути можно считать число ребер, через которые уже прошли и не учитывать пути, для которых пройденное число ребер > Long.